# Why can't change background color in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, content-management-system

I want to change background color on nav menu in wordpress site but its change only a single line - view the image. Can you please tell me what is the problem and how to fix it? Tanks!!!![enter image description here][1]

.main-navigation {

background-color: #012e43;

}

Answer (score 0):

We could help better if you share more details of your problem.

Anyway, at first check your selector (`.main-navigation`) and be sure that you chose the correct element.

Then have a look at [CSS Specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp) and for example add `!important` to override previous styling rules:

```css
background-color: #012e43 !important;
```

Also [specificity calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/) is a good website to see CSS specificity in action.